# Passing a generic javascript function as a callback doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, callback, prototype

I have a function that reads an http stream, combines the data events, and passes the response as a joined string.  If I pass the 'data' event a function in the form of `c => body.push(c)` it works as expected.  However, if I pass it `body.push` the content is never added to the array.  **Is there a reason generic prototypes can't be passed as parameters?**

Here's my function:

```
const requestPromise = function(resolve, reject) {
    return (response) => {
        let body = [];

        response.on('data', body.push);
        response.on('end', () => {
            body = body.join('');
            if (body == "") {
                reject("Body is empty");
            } else {
                resolve(body);
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: No, there is no reason that a prototype function "can't" be used as a higher-order function (ie. used as an argument to a function). The conclusion of "doesn't execute" is wrong as it *does* execute, just without the expected context. However, I would recommend reading up on how `this` is resolved in functions - as this (hah!) is crucial to understanding how ECMAScript works. Once understanding that, there is simply no question (above) left to answer.

Comment: See, perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work/3127440

Comment: While relevant to the answer, I don't think it's very clear that this was a scope issue; particularly since i never use the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push` in that case is no longer has the calling context of `body`, so you had the right idea using an arrow function. Another possible approach is to explicitly [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the method:

```
response.on('data', body.push.bind(body));
```